# I received no feedback on my PicoBlaze programming question. Are questions about programming PicoBlaze maybe more on-topic on Electronics?

Tags: discussion

So, it has been a few days, and I received no feedback about my [question about programming PicoBlaze](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70981222). I am wondering, am I more likely to receive feedback about it on Electronics Stack Exchange? I mean, the Electronics Stack Exchange is about, among other things, FPGAs, and PicoBlaze is a processor which is usually synthesized on FPGAs. People interested in electronics are more likely to know about PicoBlaze than people interested in programming, right? Still, Electronics Stack Exchange is not supposed to be about programming anything, including soft processors synthesized on FPGAs. Do you think cross-posting it on Electronics Stack Exchange is worth a try or not? Why or why not?

Comment: There are 6 questions under the picoblaze tag on Electrical Engineering including some asking about code - but you should probably ask on their [Meta site](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: Weekends are always quieter than weekdays on all sites and picoblaze does seem a pretty niche tag given that it only has 18 questions.

Comment: Another problem is, while there are many watchers of 'assembly' tag, *no one* is watching the 'picoblaze' tag on SO. OTOH, while there are only 6 questions on EE.SE, the tag has 2 watchers, which might increase the chance (in addition to the lower amount of new questions on there).

Comment: https://support.xilinx.com/s/?language=en_US&tabset-f4986=2

Comment: there are not that many people reading and answering that tag, so no bronze memebr and so on,. give it some time.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, I have tried asking it there: https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006zH3DxSAK/picoblaze-program-using-uart-for-converting-decimal-numbers-to-binary-works-in-a-simulator-but-it-does-not-work-on-real-picoblaze?language=en_US